# Error "No folder is open." while trying to select kit with cmake:quickstart

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I watched a couple of tutorials on how to create a project with CMake in VS Code.  When I select any kit with command cmake:quickstart for my project, it just throws the error "No folder is open". What is the problem?

Comment: Have you selected a folder to open? I'm pretty sure "folder" here is synonymous with what is called a "project" in many other IDEs. If not, create a new folder and open it. To learn more, read the VS Code docs: [single-folder workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_singlefolder-workspaces). If doing so solves your problem, let me know and I'll write an answer post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems broken in version 1.13.40, which VS Code pulled in mid-January.

It will be fixed, hopefully in the version 1.13.41: [possibly fix here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/pull/2954/commits/26941a72930aad56e06559255e7ac6c6ae576df0)

As a workaround, install one of the previous versions:

[VS Code Install Another Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAdpA.png)

Then select:

[List of previously released versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/168Eb.png)

Do not forget to reload VS Code.